# How Does Entity Framework Model Data from a Connecting Table?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Let's say I have a many-to-many relationship between the tables `Customers` and `Trucks`. They are joined by the table `CustomersTrucks`.

Now I'd like to add a column to `Customers`. However, the column is specific to customers associated with trucks, and not customers that are associated with other tables, such as `Vans`.

I might therefore conclude that it makes better sense to add this new column to `CustomerTrucks` instead of `Customers`. That way, I'm not adding data to the `Customers` table that would be unused in some cases.

But if I add the new column to the *connecting* table, what would that do to the entity model? Normally, I would expect the `Customers` entity to have a collection property called `Trucks`. So how would my new column in the connecting table be modeled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have normal junction table with only two columns (FKs for interconnected tables) you will not use such table as entity because EF can hide it and handle many-to-many relation directly.

Once you add any additional column to junction table it is not junction table any more and form EF perspective it is not many-to-many table any more (I'm not sure if it is still many-to-many in database terminology). Your `CustomersTrucs` became full entity with its own data which must be set in the application.

As you described your new property is not part of `Customers` table and because of that it also doesn't belong to `Customer` entity - you need `CustomersTruck` entity in your model and this entity will have two one-to-many relations (one to `Customer` and one to `Truck`). Because of that `Customer` as well as `Truck` will now have navigation property `CustomersTrucks`.